# Getting a background image to display in a blank div element

Tags: css

I'm looking to use a blank div element to display a background image but nothing is displaying unless I put something (i.e., some text) in the div element.

I need to do this because I want to display a graphic next to some text but have the graphic  vertically aligned with the text.

How do you get a background image to display in a blank div?

My Google-fu has failed me.

```
<div class="photoInfo">
lorem ipsum | 
<div style="background:url('foo.gif') no-repeat;display:inline;"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

edit:
The code below actually displays the image but I just need to nick it down like 2 or 3 pixels to have it perfectly aligned.

That's what I'm trying to achieve, any ideas?

```
<div class="photoInfo">
    Added<span class="spacer">•</span>Wed Apr 01, 2009 1:01 pm<span class="spacer">•</span>64.10 KB<span class="spacer">•</span>659x878 pixels
    <span class="spacer">•</span>
    <img src="/_assets/img/icons/new-photo-small.gif" />
</div>
<!--<div style="height:14px;width:31px;background:url('') no-repeat 0px 5px;display:inline-block;"></div>-->

.photoInfo
{
font-size:0.6em;
color:#b0bad9;
padding-bottom:15px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give this a shot!

```
one | <span style="padding-left: 20px; background: url('16x16-image.gif') no-repeat; height: 16px">two</span> | three
```

If you use a `div` instead of `span`, you'll need to set `display: inline` in the style as well.

Comment: If I get rid of the display:inline element, the div element doesn't display on the same line as the text I'm trying to align it with.

Comment: You're right -- I updated this since with a method that'll work for you. (Should I have added another answer instead?)

Comment: That will work but the text "two" shows, I guess I could make the text the same color as the background?

Comment: Your solution works if you set the padding-right element to the width of the image you're trying to display.  No need for the line-height element.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You have to give the div a size, otherwise its size its 0px x 0px.

Comment: I've tried giving the div the dimensions of the image and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Cheap work-aroound. put a non-break space (&nbsp;) in the div.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want any text, this works in Safari and Firefox (didn't test IE):

`one | <span style="padding: 16px 16px 0 0; background: url('16x16-image.gif') no-repeat; font-size: 0">&nbsp;</span> | three`

Answer (score 2):

The background should be on the photoInfo `div`, and you can position it with `background-position`. You can't have a background on something that is 0 height and width. If you increase it though it will take up space on your design.

Comment: I've tried that as well.  The photoInfo div element is 100% of the width of my container so if I specify no-repeat and left or right, it's at the very left or right of the screen while the text is centered.  I need it directly to the right of the centered text.

Answer (score 1):

`overflow:hidden` might help, or assigning a length and a width to the div.

In general, I would think there are other ways of achieving what you want. If you just want to have a text and an image horizontally aligned you can do that without putting the image into a `div`. For example, you could use `inline` and `float`.

Comment: The problem is that the text is in a div element that is 100% of the screen container's width.  The text is also centered and I need the image directly to the right of the text, vertically aligned.  Floating it L or R won't help and adding padding or a margin to the image style or image itself...

Comment: then wrap the text and the image within a div which is then centered in the page

Comment: I added some more information at the top which I think should better explain the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to move the background image without moving the div?

Try `background-position: xpos ypos;`

To move it down 3 pixels: `background-position: 0px 3px;`